# How to stop reload the entire project when change from one route to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When go to page from focused page to all inbox page from by `history.push("/Allinbox")` the entire application is loading.

I want that its goes from one route to another without refreshing the project.

This is how my routes are:

App.js

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/AllInbox" component={AllInboxPage} />
    <Route exact path="/Focused" component={FocusedPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Navigation.js

```js
if (PageName == "/AllInbox") {
  history.push("/AllInbox");
}

if (PageName == "/Focused") {
  history.push("/Focused");
}
```

AllInbox.js

```
return (
  <>
    <div className='lefter'>
      <Navigation menupage="/AllInbox" MenuID={MenuID} />
    </div>
  </>
)
```

FocusedPage.js

```
return (
  <>
    <div className='lefter'>
      <Navigation menupage="/Focused" MenuID={MenuID} />
    </div>
  </>
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV6Wu.png)

Like this is my side bar (left panel) if I go from Focused page to AllInbox page then the side bar is loading, I want that when user switch from one page to another page it should change page and need to prevent loading.

Comment: you are using the old version of react-router-dom. You need to upgrade all your packages.

Comment: thanks @KannuMandora for this, but when react-router-dom it will affect my whole project ?

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what *exactly* you mean by "entire application is loading" when navigating around the app? Can you also [edit] to include a more complete and readable [mcve] so it rather clear what the code is doing?

Comment: @KannuMandora Just FYI, old version !== "no longer works". Telling OP they ***need*** to upgrade isn't necessarily the best, or only, advice.

Comment: @DrewReese the "entire application is loading" means that if I want to go from one page to another without loading

Comment: also @DrewReese if I switch from one page to another like my side is refreshing that i don't want to refresh it

Comment: @DrewReese added image for better understanding

Comment: Loading or refreshing *what*? Is the web page reloaded, e.g. remounting the entire application, or is something just reloading or refetching some data, or something else? Using RRD `Link` or the `history` object to navigate shouldn't be reloading the page, so it's unclear what might actually be happening based on the code you've shared. This is the clarify I'm requesting. If possible, could you try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issues you describe that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese like its refresh the whole sidebar when I switch from one route to another and I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2", this version

Comment: @DrewReese again for better understanding can we connect to meet

Comment: That's not really what Stackoverflow is for. It's a Question and Answer site where your post should provide enough self-contained details for a specific issue that it is answerable. Right now there's just not enough code to make for a reproducible example on our end. This is what the [mcve] is for. You may want to take the [tour] and review our [help](/help/how-to-ask) section for more information that could improve the quality of your post and experience on SO.

Comment: @DrewReese it's ok I will trying to post the actual code in  codesandbox and then I will share you the link for that

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hoover-v47ywr?file=/src/Navigation.js this my project structure hope you understand and from my above points

Comment: Thanks. the sandbox loads. What are the reproduction steps? Clicking "AllInboxPage" and "FocusedPage" don't appear to do anything unexpected. Other than some props issues I don't see any overt issues.

Comment: @DrewReese here in codesandbox runs perfectly but in my project its refreshing page when switching routes in both cases the project structure is same but in AllInbox and Focused page there are lot of things which cannot place in codesanbox code

Comment: If you are concerned about sharing private code, we don't need that. We just need a code example that reproduces the navigation/rendering issue. The idea is that we resolve the issue there and you can take the solution and apply it against your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **React-router-V5**: simply place the `<Navigation/>` component inside `<Router/>`.
I have not added import statements, please add them wherever necessary.

**App.js:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Navigation />
        <div className="main-content">            
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/AllInbox" component={AllInboxPage} />
              <Route exact path="/Focused" component={FocusedPage} />
              <Redirect from="*" to="/Focused" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**For react-router v6:**
I suggest you use `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Routes>` instead of `<Router>` and `<Switch>` and try to use the latest version whenever possible.BrowserRouter handles the history automatically. Now, what you need is a `home` or `index` component and inside that you load other components as needed. Sidebar and/or header/footer will be inside home component, they will not be reloaded. Only content is replaced where `<Outlet />` is, based on the path chosen.
**App.js:**

```
export default function App(){
return(
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes/>
    <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> }>
      <Route index element={<AllInboxes/>} />    
      <Route path="AllInbox" element={ <AllIboxes />} />
      <Route path="Focused" element={<FocusedPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

**Home.js**

```
export default function Home(){
  return(
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet/>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but its not possible with "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2", my this version

Comment: Share your version of `react` , `react-dom` and `react-router-dom`

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2", and  "react-dom": "^18.2.0", and "react": "^18.2.0",

Comment: this is working fine for me but now one problem is that when ever switch routes left side also blinks in my project and in codesandbox exmple it only updates right side part

Comment: add a `useEffect( ( )=>{ console.log("component_name rendered") } );` inside every component, you will get to know which components are re-rendering.

Comment: like if I wish to pass data from my Allinbox and focused page to navigation so it is possible because in my project there pass data from allinbox and focused page to navigation how will can achieve tha

Comment: You can have a `const [data, setData] = useState( )` inside the `app( )` component and just pass the `setData` function to the components that can change the data. Then just pass the `data` as a prop to `Navigation` component.

Comment: If you are passing state to a lot of child components, I suggest you use the **context api**

Comment: yes in my project we have 20+ components and we have to pass from these components to navigation as props passing data

Comment: Remember, If you pass data to Navigation then it will re-render. Otherwise what's the point of passing data or event using react.

Comment: I'm curious what kind of data are you passing to Navigation?

Comment: I am passing page id and route name from every compoent to navigation component

Comment: But what purpose does that serve? Are you doing that because you want to show the active tab/option?

Comment: yes and lot of things in my navigation component manage from this page name and id

Comment: Ok, understood. In that case, you can use prop-drilling and pass the state update method of `App` component to it's children or use Context API. Look into `context api`, I feel that option will suit you better.

Comment: yes but changing to context api in my whole project its very difficult part  I think, If you see my whole project structure the you will better understand

Comment: No problem then just use the first  method. Pass the update state method of parent to all children and pass the state to navigation. Check the sandbox link above , I've used the same.

Comment: I think it should go in infinite loop i change any routes not working

Comment: I was cleaning up he code and sandbox crashed for some reason.

Comment: ok no problem and If you no issue so we can connect like google meet and let me show my project structure for better understanding

Comment: My github profile:  https://github.com/Kabira-root  Email is updated there. drop an email anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to a new page to change the contents of the page instead of creating multiple react components for each menu and displaying them based on the menu button click. Thus according to react and react-router you are displaying a new page which causes the entire page to reload.

If you just want to change the contents of the right-side container, use components and replace them correctly when each menu-item is clicked.